# if I update magisk, will I lose my installed magisk modules?

Tags: root-access, updates, magisk

[image]

I have a rooted Xiaomi smartphone with Magisk version 23. I would like to update it to version 24, or even 25.
If I update it via boot recovery or otherwise, will I lose the modules I installed on magisk version 23?
Do I risk losing more data on my phone with this update?

NW: The magisk app says to update to version 26, but this version is unstable with my phone and I don't want to do that.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the installed Magisk system located in the kernel image. Updating that should have no effect on the Magisk app and installed modules (unless you totally break the Magisk installation).

Comment: I added a magisk image of my phone. In short, magisk 23 doesn't allow me to pass the CTS profile (now on false) and I have to upgrade to magisk 24/25 to have zygisk and to pass CTS profile